# Why is the European Data Protection Supervisor linked to as the complaints office when it clearly states it isn't responsible?

Tags: bug, legal, gdpr

I have recently made a GDPR Data Request via Stack Overflow's online request wizard. In the e-mails that followed, I noticed a couple of issues of which I'm unsure whether they really are issues or just me misunderstanding the legal situation.

1. The e-mails contain the following text:

   > If you are in the EU, you have the right to make a complaint with the [The European Commission](https://edps.europa.eu/data-protection/our-role-supervisor/complaints_en) or seek to enforce your rights through judicial remedy.

   This is quite interesting in two ways:

   1. The EU institution linked to is **not** the European Commission, but rather the European Data Protection Supervisor (EDPS). As stated on the linked webpage, it is independent.
   2. The EDPS is **not** responsible for complaints against non-EU institutions or private organisations. As stated on their webpage (emphasis mine):

      > **Who can complain to us and what can you complain about?**
      > Complaints to the EDPS must relate to the processing of personal information *carried out by an EU institution*. [...]

      and also

      > **What you cannot complain to us about**
      > [...]

      > 3. The EDPS has no supervisory powers for handling complaints about the processing of personal information by national, regional or local public authorities, private companies or organisations, or not-for-profit organisations.
      >    If, for example: [...] you should contact the relevant national data protection authority and not the EDPS.
      > 4. We do not have supervisory powers to handle complaints about the processing of personal data by international organisations. You should contact the Data Protection Officer in the organisation concerned.
2. Article 77 (1) of the Regulation (EU) 2016/679 (EU GDPR) states that:

   > *Article 77*
   > *Right to lodge a complaint with a supervisory authority*
   >
   > 1. Without prejudice to any other administrative or judicial remedy, every data subject shall have the right to lodge a complaint with a supervisory authority, in particular in the Member State of his or her habitual residence, place of work or place of the alleged infringement if the data subject considers that the processing of personal data relating to him or her infringes this Regulation.

   This would mean that if the person making the request is Italian citizen, they would be able to complain to the Italian Data Protection Authority.

Now, I have -- asides from the mislabeling of the link to the EDPS' webpage -- the following questions:

1. Since the EDPS is -- per its own definition -- not responsible, why was it included in the e-mail as the complaints office?
2. Since I have the right to complain to a local authority, wouldn't it be a good idea to instead link to the EDPS' [list of national authorities](https://edpb.europa.eu/about-edpb/about-edpb/members_en)?

(Please note that I have not taken a look at the Privacy Policy regarding the responsible complaints office; also, I am not a lawyer and if my concerns are not valid, I would like to have an explanation why.)

Comment: *"wouldn't it be a good idea to instead link to the EDPS' list of national authorities?"* -  Worth noting that wouldn't cover every case. The UK implements GDPR through the UK GDPR in DPA 2018 and as they're not in the EU they're not covered by that list. IIRC they're meant to make complaints to the ICO.

Comment: Well, the UK isn't covered by the current link anyway. Also, the text specifically says "If you're in the EU", which no longer includes the UK... Maybe a separate link for UK citizens?

Comment: "The EU institution linked to is not the European Commission, but rather the European Data Protection Supervisor (EDPS)" Well each GDPR request isn't handled personally by Ursula von der Leyen, it turns out... they have specific authorities with officials for that. EDPS supposedly coordinates the national authorities listed here: https://edpb.europa.eu/about-edpb/about-edpb/members_en

Comment: @Lundin Um, yes. That's what my question is all about. (The point of the sentence you're quoting was to show that there is a mistake in the labelling, EDPS != EC.) Also, the two lists (EDPS's members, which I linked to in my question, and EDPB's members) seem to be identical, which shouldn't be that surprising.